# Flutter Q1. setState being called about 100 times in a second, while Timer periodic Duration set to 1 second, Q2. It wont stop running in background

Tags: flutter, dart, timer, setstate, dispose

Edit: Q1. is answered. please help me in the Q2. Also, please suggest if i should make a new thread of this question ?

**Q1.** I am making a digital clock in my app. I have set my Timer, so that setState should run after each second. and in the UI, it seems fine. But in terminal you can see it runs a lot of times in a second. How to stop that?

**Q2.** I have two pages in flutter app. Even when i move to secondpage (using `navigator.push`), the timer still runs in background. ( I know it because i am printing it in terminal also).
Also, I already tried  canceling my Timer in `dispose` method. it does not work.
Also, If I use `navigator.pushRemoved`, it solves the problem of Timer being run in background, but i wont be able to go back to this page.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:provider_2_practice/controller/controller_file.dart';

import 'new_screen.dart';

class MyHomePageUI extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyHomePageUI> createState() => _MyHomePageUIState();
}

class _MyHomePageUIState extends State<MyHomePageUI> {

  Timer? timer ;
  String abc ='df-1'; //default value: 'df-1'

  String refreshTime(){
    timer?.cancel();

    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      if(mounted){
        setState( () {
          abc = DateFormat('hh:mm:ss a').format(DateTime.now());
          print(abc);
        } );
      }
    });

    return abc ;
  }

@override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
  print('test');
  timer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue[900],
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){

           Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewScreen()));
 
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add,  color: Colors.white),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ),


      body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(height:100,),
          Text(refreshTime(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 45, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: Colors.white70),),
          Text('current time', style: TextStyle(  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: Colors.white),),

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: first page]

[image: second page, Timer still running. see the consol]

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that prevents you from creating that periodic `Timer` multiple times.  Every time you call `refreshTime`, if `timer` is not `null`, you either should A. do nothing, B. cancel the existing `Timer` before creating a new one.

Comment: Looks like you're calling the refreshTime method in the build method or somewhere that is getting affected by change in the state causing rebuild. Can you show how you're calling the method?

Comment: OMi Shah, you are right. I am calling it inside build() method. What should i do ? I have updated the code. please check

Comment: What should i do ? If I use my variable, abc, directly in TextWidget, it shows the default value.

Answer (score 2):

Every time `refreshTime()` is called you are creating a new timer **on top of any existing timers**. To solve this first cancel any existing timers. So like,

```
  String refreshTime(){
    timer?.cancel();
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      setState( () {
        abc = DateFormat('hh:mm:ss a').format(DateTime.now());
        print(abc);
      } );
    });

    return abc ;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked.
but you forgot to answer 2nd question. When i go to another screen, the timer keeps on running. It is not terminated in the widget tree ? How ?
I tried using dispose method. and also used 'mounted'

Comment: @SaadMansoor does it also keep running after applying this solution?

Comment: yes. I also have tried using if(mounted).  It still runs.

Comment: @SaadMansoor sorry, I don't know exactly why that is

Answer (score -1):

Put this in init(). And put `timer?.cancel()` inside onClick of the button, (which you click to go to the next page.). And to print on UI, instead of terminal use the variable `abc`.

```
timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) {
  if(mounted){
    setState( () {
      abc = DateFormat('hh:mm:ss a').format(DateTime.now());
    } );

  }
  print(abc);
});
```